# How to install gstreamer nvcodec vs nvdec/nvenc plugins on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia, nvdec

Installed gstreamer and gstreamer-plugins-bad on ubuntu 20.04 via the apt repo.  I also installed the Video_Codec SDK 11.0 from Nvidia.

The gst-ispect command shows me nvenc and nvdec is installed and I am able to use hardware acceleration when playing videos.

What I have found however is reference to the nvcodec at [gstreamer nvcodec doc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/nvcodec/index.html?gi-language=c).

I don't have this plugin when I look in get-inspect.

Have also compile opencv with support for gstreamer.

Ultimately I want to be able to use gstreamer in python with opencv and get hardware accelerated decoding of my streams.  What I can't seem to do is create a pipeline which converts the output of nvdec to play in appsink.  The nvcodec plugin I mentioned earlier appears to have this capability.

So is there a way to install nvcodec on Ubuntu 20.04 or is there a way to create a pipeline that decodes using the nvdec plugin and feeds into the appsink so that I can consume that in opencv.

Comment: The `nvcodec` plugin is included in the `1.18` version of GStreamer. In version `1.16` it's two separate plugins (`nvdec` and `nvenc`).

Answer (score 1):

**nvcodec** is available from GStreamer 1.18 onwards. Since you are on Ubuntu 20.04, it installs GStreamer 1.16 by default, which supports **nvenc** and **nvdec**. Upgrade your OS to Ubuntu 22.04, and it'll install GStreamer 1.20 by default, and you'll get nvcodec automatically.